# Passing a pointer to a parameter into a method in php?

Tags: php, pointers, methods, parameters

I have an interesting situation and I'm not quite sure what the best way to handle this is.  I have a method that I want to use with several different parameters in my class. Ideally, the simplest way (if possible) would be to pass a pointer to the parameter.  Essentially here's what I'd like to do:

```
private $a = "bob";
private $b = "jim";

private function setName($parameter) {
  $parameter = $parameter . " smith";
}

echo($this->a); // would echo "bob"
echo($this->b); // would echo "jim";

$this->setName($this->a);
$this->setName($this->b);

echo($this->a); // would echo "bob smith"
echo($this->b); // would echo "jim smith";
```

Is this something that is even possible?  I tried variations of adding a & like you would any other variable (e.g. &$this->a and $this->&a) but it didn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured out the answer to my own question. It seems that the correct method is to include the & operator in the method, rather than attach it to the passed parameter... for example:

```
private function setName(&$parameter) { // include pointer here
  $parameter = $parameter . " smith";
}
```

Stil have more testing to do, but it appears that this is working the way I intended.